# Valid uses of raw pointers to arbitrary memory location in C#

Tags: c#, pointers, unmanaged, unmanaged-memory

In the following code I build a pointer to a struct located at an arbitrary memory location:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct S
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] int f0;
    [FieldOffset(4)] int f4;

    public static void Main() {
        unsafe {
            S* rawPtr = (S*)0x1234;
            rawPtr->f0 = 42;
        }
    }
}
```

If I change `f4`'s type to `object` instead of `int`, I get the error [Compiler Error CS0208: Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('type')](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/x2estayf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

What are the constaints on `struct S` that allow building pointers on that type, at the `CIL` (not just `C#`) level?

[This page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/y31yhkeb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) says `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `char`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`, `bool`, enums and pointers are allowed, as well as "user-defined struct type that contains fields of unmanaged types only", but doesn't specify what an unmanaged type is.

Comment: Coincidentally, unmanaged types are `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `char`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`, `bool`, enums and pointers.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I kinda guessed that, but I'd like to have a clear statement from the official documentation or ECMA 335 standard. Also, I'm not sure if the struct should have a `StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)`, or similar requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find an easily navigable version of ECMA-335 online, but [ECMA-334 paragraph 27.2](http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334%3a_27.2_Pointer_types) says:

> An *unmanaged-type* is any type that isn’t a *reference-type*, a
>   *type-parameter*, or a generic *struct-type* and contains no fields whose
>   type is not an *unmanaged-type*. In other words, an *unmanaged-type* is
>   one of the following:
>
> - `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `char`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`, or `bool`.
> - Any *enum-type*.
> - Any *pointer-type*.
> - Any non-generic user-defined *struct-type* that contains fields of *unmanaged-types* only.
>
> [*Note*: Constructed types and *type-parameters* are never
>   *unmanaged-types*. *end note*]

The packing mode of a structure does not seem to be relevant to this distinction.